# Copy datas from SQLDB into hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, architecture, apache-beam, debezium

I am studying a use case where we are going to move datas from a SQL database (600TB ~100 tables) into a transformed format into hadoop. We don't have logs enabled in the SQL DB. We decided to copy the datas as a datamart view and to refresh this view every week. The copied datas will be erased every week to be rewritten.

This SQL DB is used for reporting purposes that is derived from the datalake. This OLTP database is an old system we are replacing progressivly. The dataset that is copied is deleted every week and copied again (refreshed).

- 80% of data copy is straight with no transformation.
- 20% has redesign.

We identified 3 options :

1. AirFlow + Beam for the processing
2. ETL (informatica) was excluded
3. Kafka (connect, stream, sink into hadoop) with optionnaly CDC Debezium

What do you think is a best approach regarding : performance, overall time to deliver, data architecture ?

Thanks for help  !
[image]

Comment: Are you really planning to drop and re-load 600TB of data every week? Is there no overlap in the datasets from one week to another? How much data transformation is there - is it basically a straight copy of the source table or a fundamental redesign (OLTP to OLAP)? Why are you moving the data out of a SQL DB into Hadoop?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. This SQL DB is used for reporting purposes that is derived from the datalake. This OLTP database is an old system we are replacing progressivly. The dataset that is copied is deleted every week and copied again (refreshed). 80% of data copy is straight. 20% has redesign.

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts - for what they are worth:

1. I would definitely not be looking to copy 600TB per week. Given that the majority of this data will not have changed from week to week (I assume) then you should be looking to only copy across the data that has changed. As your data in Hadoop will be partitioned then you would mainly be inserting new data into new partitions - for those records that have changed you will just be dropping/reloading a few partitions
2. I would copy all the necessary data into a staging area in Hadoop as-is (without transformation) and then process it on the Hadoop platform to produce the data you actually need - you can then drop the staging area data if you want
3. Data processing tool - if you already have experience of a specific toolset within your company then use that; don't multiply the toolsets in use unless there is critical functionality required that is not available within existing tools. If this one process is all you are going to be using this toolset for then it probably doesn't matter which one you use - pick one that is quickest to learn/deploy. If this toolset is going to be expanded to other use cases then I would definitely use a dedicated ETL/ELT tool rather than use a coding solution (why have you discarded Informatica as a solution?)

---

The following is definitely an opinion...

If you are building a new analytical platform, I am surprised that you are using Hadoop. Hadoop is legacy technology that has been superseded by more modern and capable Cloud data platforms (Snowflake, etc.).

Also, Hadoop is a horrible platform to try and run analytics on (it's ok as just a data lake to hold data while you decide what you want to do with it). Trying to run queries on it that don't align with how that data is partitioned gives really bad performance (for non-trivial dataset sizes). For example, if your transactions are partitioned by date then running a query to sum transaction values in the last week will run quickly. However, running a query to sum transactions for a specific account (or group of accounts) will perform very badly